# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied with subprocess.check_output

Tags: python

I am using the file `/sys/class/net/NIC_NAMES/speed` to get the output from the file. The  **NIC_NAMES** part is varying hence it could be "eth1" or "eth0" etc. here i'm getting that value from **Current_inf** hence Current_inf is a variable which i'm looking to call every-time to get the **NIC_NAME** value . What Will be right approach to call the variable to get the output.

> While calling it Via **subprocess.check_output** i'm getting into
>   below error.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import netifaces
>>> import socket
>>> import re
>>>
>>> Current_inf = netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][1]
>>> print Current_inf
eth0
>>> spd = subprocess.check_output('/sys/class/net/%s/speed' % (Current_inf))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.10/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.10/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.10/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

> When i call it Direct from the OS :

## cat /sys/class/net/eth0/speed

2000

Please guide me how appropriatly i can use string formatting , Whether `%` or `.format`. Though i'm using python 2.7.10.

Secondly as a newbie to python , I would like to have understand How a variable can be called into the file configuration path Like the Situation i have above where i want to call `Current_inf` to be called up as a variable.

Your inputs will be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: `>>> spd = subprocess.check_output(['cat', '/sys/class/net/{}/speed'.format(Current_inf)])` may work better.

Comment: 2.7 works fine with `.format`, just as `3.6` works fine with `%`. `.format` is preferred, since you don't have to think whether your argument(s) need to be a tuple (amongst other reasons).

Comment: "Secondly as a newbie to python": please focus on one question per question.

Comment: @Evert, thx again for your inputs, i'm testing it.

Comment: @Evert, your solution is working, I'll take that into consideration while putting the ques to the board. I just asked that to have a better solution in hand as "Eugene"  proposed a solution as well without sub-process, So, if the variable getting called up across thousand lines so, what will be approach will it has latency or in others words what will be faster.

Comment: A native `open` call will be faster than spawning a subprocess, but it sounds like you may be going for premature optimisation. I really wouldn't bother with that now. More importantly, if you just need to read the file, nothing else, just open it in Python. That's more natural than running a subprocess anyway.

Comment: @Evert, Thats correct .. same notion i have  `open` will be faster rather opening an another fork with `subprocess`. 

by the way what do you mean by `premature optimisation` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use `subprocess` module to read a plain file. You can just use: `open('/sys/class/net/%s/speed' % Current_inf).read()`

Comment: Eugene Morozov,  Its working , i just added `.strip` at the end to cut down the `\n' char.

Comment: Eugene,  i have added  `open('/sys/class/net/{}/speed' .format(Current_inf)).read().strip()`  into my notes :) 

Its working as well, i beleive there will be no harm to use it as its going forward with new versions as well.